# When opportunity stage is updated ,related deal stage should be updated accordingly.Please help me to find error in the code

Tags: trigger

```
trigger updateRelatedDealRenewalStage on Opportunity (after update,after insert)
{
  set<Id> OppId = new set <Id>();
  map<Id,Opportunity> OpportunityMap = new map<Id,Opportunity>();
  List<Related_Deals__c> relateddeals = new List<Related_Deals__c>();

  for(Opportunity opt : trigger.new) {
      OppId.add(opt.Id);
      OpportunityMap.put(opt.Id, opt);
  }


  relateddeals = [SELECT Deal_Stage__c, Opportunity__c, Id FROM Related_Deals__c WHERE Id IN : OppId];
  List<Related_Deals__c> NewId = new List<Related_Deals__c>();

  if(relateddeals.size() > 0) {
     for(Related_Deals__c con : relateddeals) {
        con.Deal_Stage__c = OpportunityMap.get(con.Id).StageName;
        NewId.add(con);
     }
     update NewId;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your query for related deals is using opportunity ids in the where clause which would return no matches

Answer (score 0):

Your `relateddeals` query is wrong. It should be like below:

```
relateddeals = [SELECT Deal_Stage__c, Opportunity__c, Id FROM Related_Deals__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN : OppId];
```

Notice that in the `WHERE` part of the query you queried the `Related_Deals__c` records by their `Id`, but you were providing a list of Opportunity Ids in the `OppId` variable. If you want to get all `Related_Deals__c` that are related to the Opporunities in the `OppId` list, you need to check if the value of the field `Opportunity__c` is in the `OppId` list, like I did in the query above.

Also, the `IF` part of your trigger could look like below, since you are updating **all** `relateddeals`, there is no need to have that additional `NewId` list.

```
if(relatedDeals.size() > 0) {
     for(Related_Deals__c con : relatedDeals) {
        con.Deal_Stage__c = OpportunityMap.get(con.Id).StageName;
     }
     update relatedDeals;
 }
```

Finally, you should be more careful with your variable names if you want to know what's going on in your code after you return to it in a month or two. For example, your `NewId` list should probably be named `relatedDealsToUpdate`.